# Doctrine prevent the same specific pair of values in two columns

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a Doctrine's entity `Cart` with these two columns:

- `$user` (a ManyToOne column referencing to User entity)
- `$status` (a string field with two possible values: `pending` and `completed`)

...and **I have to prevent two 'pending' carts for the same user**.

How could I do this?.

[UniqueConstraint](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-uniqueconstraint) is not the solution, since a user must be able to have two or more completed carts, but one only pending cart.

On the other hand I could implement a [prePersist](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events) listener and check for duplicate values before insertions, but *i don't like this solution because I don't want to make extra queries to database*.

Any solution?

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to check if the user already has a pending cart, before creating a new?

Comment: also think so, add a method hasPending() that checks for that and if(!$e->hasPending()){add() }

Comment: @Daniel and john, perhaps is the best solution, thanks. My User has a method getCurrentCart() where i filter for the 'pending' cart, I can check if $user->hasCurrentCart() and then create a new one. Thanks.

Comment: An elegant way would be to make a validator on user which will check for the constraint you are explaining. This way, you can manage having a better error flow (showing error message to user, logging this kind of unexpected errors and so on). However, I would not recommand using the solution exposed by @John. The reason is that you have no trace of what could have been wrong. More over, entites are not supposed to embed this kind of logic. It would be better to extract it and make a whole service or validator.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, following the advice and [Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html) I opted for this solution:

**Constraint class**

```
<?php  
namespace MyBundle\Validator\Constraints;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
 * @Annotation
 *
 */
class UniquePendingCart extends Constraint
{
    public $message = 'Only one pending cart by user';

    public function getTargets()
    {
        return self::CLASS_CONSTRAINT;
    }

    public function validatedBy()
    {
        return 'my.validator.unique_pending_cart';
    }
}
```

**Validator service**
Injecting my `CartRepository` service:

```
my.validator:
    class: AppBundle\Validator\Constraints\UniquePendingCartValidator
    arguments:
       - @my.cart_repository
    tags:
        - name: validator.constraint_validator
        - alias: my.validator.unique_pending_cart
```

**Constraint validator** class

```
<?php
namespace MyBundle\Validator\Constraints;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectRepository;
use Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccess;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Exception\UnexpectedTypeException;

use Bshop\AppBundle\Model\Interfaces\OrderInterface;

class UniquePendingCartValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    protected $repository;

    public function __construct(ObjectRepository $repository)
    {
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }

    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        if (!$constraint instanceof UniquePendingCart) {
            throw new UnexpectedTypeException($constraint, 
                __NAMESPACE__.'\UniquePendingCart');
        }

        $isValid = $this->isStatusValid($value);

        if (!$isValid) {
            $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
                ->addViolation();
        }
    }

    protected function isStatusValid($cart)
    {
        // use repository to find another possible pending cart 
        return true;
    }
}
```

And then apply constraint in my `Cart` entity

```
<?php
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use MyBundle\Validator\Constraints as MyAssert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @MyAssert\UniquePendingCart
 */
class Cart {
    // ...
}
```

Now, I can validate a $cart and verify that is valid...

```
$cart = // my cart

$validator = $this->get("validator");
$errors = $validator->validate($cart);

if (0 !== count($errors)) {
    // ops, exception...
}
```

Comment: That's what I meant in my comment :p It needs a little effort but is way more flexible. It does also respect entities' purpose :)